# Bash script to run last command with valgrind

Tags: bash, valgrind

I am pretty inexperienced with bash. I am trying to save the last run command as a variable, this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

prev=$(fc -ln -1)
echo $prev
```

This doesn't print anything. Once I save the last command, I plan on coding this line:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full $prev
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`fc` references the history of the current shell.  When run inside a shell script it refers to history of that new shell.  If you use an alias or shell function, then `fc` will operate within the current shell.  You can also source a script file for the same effect.

```
$ cat go
#!/bin/bash

set -o history
echo a b c
fc -nl -1

$ ./go
a b c
         echo a b c

$ alias zz='fc -nl -1 | tr a-z A-Z'
$ zz
         ALIAS ZZ='FC -NL -1 | TR A-Z A-Z'
```

Comment: What does this script do?

Comment: They're both just examples.  `zz` is outputting the last command in uppercase.

Comment: `/home/undergrad/3/rrudziti/scripts/val.sh: line 1: $: command not found
a b c
  echo a b c
/home/undergrad/3/rrudziti/scripts/val.sh: line 8: $: command not found
/home/undergrad/3/rrudziti/scripts/val.sh: line 9: a: command not found
a b c
/home/undergrad/3/rrudziti/scripts/val.sh: line 12: $: command not found
/home/undergrad/3/rrudziti/scripts/val.sh: line 13: $: command not found
/home/undergrad/3/rrudziti/scripts/val.sh: line 14: ALIAS: command not found`

Comment: OK, I didn't write you a script to solve your problem.  I posted an interactive shell session demonstrating the concept I wanted to explain - namely that you need to use an alias or function to get what you want.  The `$` above are my shell prompts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [aliases](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) rather than a script, something like:

```
alias val='valgrind --leak-check=full'
alias vallast='val $(history 2 | head -1 | cut -d" " -f3-)'
```

As explained in the link, you can add these lines to your `.bashrc`.

BTW, the latter can also be executed as:

```
val !!
val !-1 #same
```

Or if you want to `valgrind` the program you ran 2 commands ago:

```
val !-2
```

These history commands are explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps).